# cannot deploy multiple hosts in capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, deployment, capistrano

I'm using capistrano to deploy rails app to about 20 servers, it works ok when server num ~ 10, when increase it to >~ 10, it doesnt work anymore

Here is the error

```
cap aborted!
Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:44:in `write'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:44:in `negotiate!'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:32:in `initialize'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `new'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `initialize'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:232:in `new'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:232:in `start'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `call'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `with'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:155:in `with_ssh'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:49:in `upload!'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-3.6.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
/Users/khiem-nguyen/workspace/ruby/nenga-onepiece/cl-chef/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
The deploy has failed with an error: Broken pipe
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed    


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:    


 DEBUG Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh 0.0%    

 DEBUG Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh 0.0%    

  INFO [7c256e12] Running /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh on onepiece-web07    

 DEBUG [7c256e12] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv" PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" ; /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh )    

  INFO Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh 100.0%    

  INFO Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh 100.0%    

  INFO [846397ba] Finished in 0.065 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).    

  INFO [3e8f8a49] Running /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh on onepiece-web03    

 DEBUG [3e8f8a49] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv" PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" ; /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh )    

  INFO [7c256e12] Finished in 0.037 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).    

  INFO [264aa0db] Running /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh on onepiece-web01    

 DEBUG [264aa0db] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv" PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" ; /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh )    

  INFO [a8720934] Finished in 0.265 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).    

  INFO [3e8f8a49] Finished in 0.043 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).    

  INFO [264aa0db] Finished in 0.038 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).    

 DEBUG Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh 0.0%    

  INFO Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh 100.0%    

  INFO [3d959fa8] Running /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh on onepiece-web02    

 DEBUG [3d959fa8] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv" PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" ; /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-nenga-onepiece-production-khiem-nguyen.sh )    

  INFO [3d959fa8] Finished in 0.045 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

I think there's something related to ssh max connection???

Cap version:3.6.1
SSH kit: 1.9.0

Comment: I suggest re-running the deploy with the `--trace` flag as instructed in the error message. This will give more information about where the error is occurring. Please also post what version of Capistrano and SSHKit you are using.

Comment: I just added trace log and cap version here. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try tweaking MaxStartups in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the server of your Git server.

Default value is 10:30:60, the first 10 limits this.

MaxStartups
        Specifies the maximum number of concurrent unauthenticated con-
        nections to the sshd daemon.  Additional connections will be
        dropped until authentication succeeds or the LoginGraceTime
        expires for a connection.   The default is 10.

```
    Alternatively, random early drop can be enabled by specifying the
    three colon separated values "start:rate:full" (e.g.,
    "10:30:60").  sshd will refuse connection attempts with a proba-
    bility of "rate/100" (30%) if there are currently "start" (10)
    unauthenticated connections.  The probability increases linearly
    and all connection attempts are refused if the number of unau-
    thenticated connections reaches "full" (60).
```

Answer (score 0):

SSHKit (the SSH layer in Capistrano) uses connection pooling. This means that it maintains an SSH connection for each host. If you are seeing a broken pipe error when you increase the hosts, the only thing I can think of is that perhaps a firewall or gateway (i.e. an ssh proxy) is limiting the number of simultaneous connections.

As a workaround, you can try disabling the connection pool. Add the following to your `deploy.rb`:

```
# Disable connection pool
SSHKit::Backend::Netssh.pool.idle_timeout = 0
```

This will make your deployments slower, but it might solve the connection errors.

Comment: I found the reason is the connection limitation of git server. Thanks alot